# Linking files (php)

Tags: php, html, file, hyperlink

I asked before how to get the content of a directory and I got suggested dirscan() which was exactly what I needed. 
Now I want it so that the files are links redirected to the corresponding file. So if there was a file named 'book.pdf', you could click it and it would open 'book.pdf'.
Right now I did this:

```
<?php 
$dir = '/books';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file) {
    echo "$file<br/>";
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is `/books` located relative to the web root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using HTML anchor tag?
`<a href="/books/$file">$file</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Uh, make them links?

```
echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a>"
```

This is not so much about PHP, more about (very basic) HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to php and wasn't sure how to use anchors in a php echo.

Comment: I don't think it's about very basic HTML, but about the understanding of the HTTP-mechanism and the client- and serverside programming concept.

Answer (score 1):

`echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you just make them a html link? Quick piece of code:

```
  echo "<a href=\"{$dir}/{$file}\">{$file}</a><br/>";
```